# OpenMP, reason for slowdown with more threads? (no sharing/no rand() (I think..) )

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I am running my code on Intel® Xeon(R) CPU X5680 @ 3.33GHz × 12. Here is a fairly simple OpenMP pseudo code (the OpenMP parts are exact, just normal code in between is changed for compactness and clarity):

```
vector<int> myarray(arraylength,something);

omp_set_num_threads(3);
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic)
    for(int j=0;j<pr.max_iteration_limit;j++)
    {
        vector<int> temp_array(updated_array(a,b,myarray));
        for(int i=0;i<arraylength;i++)
        {
            #pragma omp atomic
            myarray[i]+=temp_array[i];
        }
    }
}
```

all parameters taken by temp_array function are copied so that there would be no clashes. Basic structure of temp_array function:

```
vector<int> updated_array(myClass1 a, vector<myClass2> b, vector<int> myarray)
{
    //lots of preparations, but obviously there are only local variables, since 
    //function only takes copies

    //the core code taking most of the time, which I will be measuring:
    double time_s=time(NULL);
    while(waiting_time<t_wait) //as long as needed 
    {
        //a fairly short computaiton
        //generates variable: vector<int> another_array
        waiting_time++;
    }
    double time_f=time(NULL);

    cout<<"Thread "<<omp_get_thread_num()<<" / "<<omp_get_num_threads()
        << " runtime "<<time_f-time_s<<endl;

    //few more changes to the another_array

    return another_array;
}
```

Questions and my attempts to resolve it:

adding more threads (with omp_set_num_threads(3);) does create more threads, but each thread does the job slower. E.g. 1: 6s, 2: 10s, 3: 15s ... 12: 60s. 
(where to "job" I refer to the exact part of the code I pointed out as core, (NOT the whole omp loop or so) since it takes most of the time, and makes sure I am not missing anything additional)

There are no rand() things happening inside the core code.

Dynamic or static schedule doesnt make a difference here of course (and I tried..)

There seem to be no sharing possible in any way or form, thus I am running out of ideas completely... What can it be? I would be extremely grateful if you could help me with this (even with just ideas)!

p.s. The point of the code is to take myarray, do a bit of montecarlo on it with a single thread, and then collect tiny changes and add/substract to the original array.

Comment: I compile with:
g++ -std=c++11 -fopenmp -O3 -Wall part.cc -o part

(in case that matters... havent tried to take off O3, and see if the speedup happens... that's probably my next thing, though it wouldnt help, since without O3 or O2, the thing is running dead slow.

Comment: Your code doesn't look like it is parallelisable : `myarray` is written to and read from (when calling `updated_array()`) within the loop parallelised loop -- this is a race condition that you haven't dealt with. The results from a serial and parallel execution can be quite different.

Comment: myarray gets written only in atomic section, and gets read from only when copying in the function (I do not pass my array, by pointer or reference, just make a copy, by calling how I did, correct?). Thus there should be no race conditions.
Moreover, the slowdown measured is only when things deal with copy, inside the function. (not when copying).

Comment: p.s. even if I comment out the atomic part (the only place myarray gets changed) there is not speedup. So problem is the interaction between core code running in one thread and in another.

Comment: Why did you duplicate this question?

Comment: as I said in the duplication, I skimmed it down, to narrow the possible problems, and made it more accessible to read through. However there is more information in the original one, and thus if one gets interested beyond basics, it is useful to have as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

OpenMP may implement the atomic access using a mutex, when your code will suffer from heavy contention on that mutex. This will result in a significant performance hit.
If the work in `updated_array()` dominates the cost of the parallel loop, you'de better put the whole of the second loop inside a critical section:

```
{   // body of parallel loop
    vector<int> temp_array = updated_array(a,b,myarray);
    #pragma omp critical(UpDateMyArray)
    for(int i=0;i<arraylength;i++)
        myarray[i]+=temp_array[i];
}
```

However, your code looks broken (essentially not threadsafe), see my comment.

Comment: yes, I could, I just wrote it when I was not sure about the times.

regarding the whole code, my answer under your comment: no race condition because it deals with copies only? right?